# Adding extreme value distributed noise (with µ=0,σ=10) to a vector of numbers in R

Tags: r, random, noise

I have the following matrix

```
Measurement Treatment
38 A
14 A
54 A
69 A
20 B
36 B
35 B
10 B
11 C
98 C
88 C
14 C
```

I want to add extreme value distributed noise (with mean=0 and sd=10) to the Measurement values. How can I achieve that in R?

I found `revd` in `extRemes` package, but it does not work as expected. Does `devd` from the same package do what I want to do? (but it does not allow for mean and sd to be defined)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your measure as the mean for the noise, then you can do this:

```
measure = round(runif(10,0,30),0)
data = data.frame(measure)
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
   data$measure1[i] = rnorm(1,data$measure[i],10)
} 
data
   measure  measure1
1        6  6.281557
2       12 -5.780177
3       18 13.529773
4       26 33.665584
5       14 12.666614
6       24 41.146132
7        5 -1.850390
8       14 16.728703
9       13 26.082601
10      13 14.066475
```

EDIT: You can avoid the for loop with this instead:

```
data$measure1 = data$measure + rnorm(1,0,10)
```